# How accurate is cumtrapz in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-analysis, integration

Say I have a set of discrete acceleration data and want to integrate it to get a set of velocity data.  How accurate is the [`cumtrapz` (Cumulative trapezoidal numerical integration)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html) integrator in MATLAB?

Does it follow that the more acceleration data I have (for whatever fixed timescale), the better results I'll get from `cumptrapz`?

Comment: look up the standard error estimates for the cumulative trapezoidal method (spoiler: for an uniform data grid with spacing $h$, the method is second order accurate, i.e., the error is ${\cal O}(h^2)$). if your acceleration data is non-uniformly spaced, have a look at [this scicomp post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/numerical-integration-of-non-uniform-acceleration-samples).

Comment: @GoHokies, consider converting your comment to an answer, as it certainly does answer this question completely.